# MySQL : xyz_dept and number of employee working in xyz_dept using nested queries

Tags: mysql

I would like to retrieve the find out no.of employees working in “Sales” department along with "sales" in the retrieved table as:

```
+-------+------------------+
| name  | count(e.dept_id) |
+-------+------------------+
| Sales |                3 |
+-------+------------------+
```

I can write it by following query:

```
mysql> select d.name, count(e.dept_id)
    -> from   department d, employee e
    -> where  e.dept_id = d.department_id and d.name='sales';
```

but as I've been taught nested queries improve the efficiency of the query.
so I'm trying to rewrite the same using **nested query**.
but I could go only to this:

```
mysql> select   count(*)
    -> from     employee 
    -> where    dept_id = (select department_id
    ->                    from   department
    ->                    where  name='sales');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+
```

I tried many combinations but no hope. How can I obtain below table using **nested query**:

```
+-------+------------------+
| name  | count(e.dept_id) |
+-------+------------------+
| Sales |                3 |
+-------+------------------+
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query:

```
   select d.name, count(e.dept_id) 
   from employee e
   INNER JOIN (select name,department_id from department where name='sales') d
          on d.department_id = e.dept_id;
```